# is there any open source library available for generate barcode in iphone?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Barcode Generation inside of IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759073/barcode-generation-inside-of-ios)

Now i am using oblinear library to generate bar code image. In the generated  bar code it shows trial so i have idea  to move some other  library is there any open source  library is available in ios to generate bar code.
  If any one knows please share that library and sample code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Owen - the OP wants to create barcodes, not scan them.

Comment: @rmaddy omg sorry about that, removed my comment.

Comment: ya correct wants to create barcode image