# barcode generation containing user data

Tags: ios, iphone

How can I generate a barcode for unique user with few other details in Xcode (iphone) ?

for e.g. user - joe Bloggs received 100 points

I would like create a barcode for joe bloggs with 100 points.

Thanks

Comment: you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759073/barcode-generation-inside-of-ios

Comment: does it have to be barcode? Or can you use QR? QR codes are more versatile in terms of amount and type of information you can store in them.

Comment: I am open to both .. QR code is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following library free on github: https://github.com/netshade/Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes.