# How to generate a EAN13 barcode?

Tags: ios, swift, barcode, ean-13

I'm trying to create a simple EAN13 image to show a barcode from a String.

I tried with this code but it can only generate a code128. What can I use to generate a EAN13?

```
class Barcode {

  class func fromString(string : String) -> UIImage? {

      let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)
      let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator")
      filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
      return UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage)
  }
}

let img = Barcode.fromString("1234567890123")
```

Comment: `CIFilter` doesn't appear to support EAN13, just QR Code, Aztec, Code 128, and PDF 417.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Barcode Generation inside of IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759073/barcode-generation-inside-of-ios)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this [EAN13BarcodeGenerator](https://github.com/astrokin/EAN13BarcodeGenerator)

Usage is pretty simple:

```
BarCodeView *barCodeView = [[BarCodeView alloc] initWithFrame:kBarCodeFrame];
[self.view addSubview:barCodeView];
[barCodeView setBarCode:GetNewRandomEAN13BarCode()];
```

Comment: Swift version: let rect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 55, width: 113, height: 100)
        let barcodeView = BarCodeView(frame: rect)
        self.view.addSubview(barcodeView)
        
        barcodeView.barCode = "4012345678901"

Answer (score -6):

my two cents for **osx**..

```
func barCodeFromString(string : String, destSize: NSSize) -> NSImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: .ascii)
    guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator") else{
        return nil
    }

    filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
    guard let ciImage : CIImage = filter.outputImage else{
        return nil
    }

    let c_size = ciImage.extent.size

    let w_ratio = destSize.width/c_size.width
    let h_ratio = destSize.height/c_size.height
    let ratio = w_ratio>h_ratio ? h_ratio : w_ratio
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: ratio, y: ratio)
    let scaled = ciImage.transformed(by: transform)

    let rep = NSCIImageRep(ciImage: scaled)
    let nsImage = NSImage(size: rep.size)
    nsImage.addRepresentation(rep)
    return nsImage
}
```

Comment: The question is asking how to generate an EAN13 barcode, not a Code128 barcode.

Comment: i know.. that's why I wrote "my 2 cents..." :)

Comment: The goal is to answer the question.

Comment: simply change from "CICode128BarcodeGenerator" to: "CIQRCodeGenerator"