# Barcode generator code or SDK for ipad

Tags: ios, iphone

Hi I'm working on a iPad project and that needs to generate a barcode image of given string. I have seen many codes and download several SDK, but it wont help me. Please, can anyone to help me by providing barcode generating code or SDK in iPhone. Thank you all.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Have you tried zbar sdk http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/

Comment: @kb920 Actually i need to only generate the barcode not to scan

Comment: https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library worked for me...

https://github.com/netshade/Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes

Answer (score 2):

you can refer [Barcode Generation from within iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759073/barcode-generation-inside-of-ios) for previous answers

Also there are some opensource working codes too

http://www.onbarcode.com/tutorial/iphone-barcode-generator-guide.html

http://www.onbarcode.com/products/iphone_barcode/

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2014/04/23/create-barcodes-in-ios-with-ease-using-nuclios-obj-c-amp-c.aspx

https://github.com/yeahdongcn/RSBarcodes_Swift